# Deutsche Bahn Sparpreis Europa ticket validity

Tags: trains, tickets

I have booked a ticket (Sparpreis Europa, class 1) via Deutsche Bahn website from Munich to Vienna and there are 2 points I wanted to clarify:

- My ticket says "München+City ->Wien". Does it mean that on the day of departure from Munich, I can use all local transport as well with my ticket? If yes, then how will I validate my ticket as its for a different train?
- It's a "Sparpreis Europa" ticket, so it's not flexible, however my ticket says validity from Day 1 - Day 2. Does it mean that if I miss my train then I catch another one with same ticket?

Comment: Is "Dbahn" a common term or even official brand? I only ever see "DB" or "Deutsche Bahn".

Comment: See [City-Ticket Geltungsbereiche](https://www.bahn.de/angebot/weiterreise/cityticket-geltungsbereich) for an overview for each city (often with a PDF map showing where it is valid)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A Sparpreis Europa ticket is indeed not flexible. You are expected to take the trains you selected during booking. However, if you miss a connection due to a delay (or something else that the railways is responsible for), or one of your trains is cancelled, your ticket then becomes a standard ticket, valid on any train on the route, and that between the two dates mentioned. That is the reason that is has a longer validity than needed for the trains you booked.

And as with all train tickets in Germany there is no need to "validate" anything. You can indeed take public transit to the main station in Munich with this ticket, and all you need to do is have it with you, and show it to a ticket inspector if requested. There are no gates or pre-boarding ticket inspections on any metro system in Germany.

Comment: The longer validity is also for any local trains which are part of the ticket, since the Zugbindung (at least in Germany) only applies to long distance trains (ICE, IC, EC etc.). So if you e.g. have to take a local train after the ICE, you can take any other local train as well to your destination, even without delays (within the given validity dates).

Comment: "if you miss a connection", only if that's because the previous train was so late, not if you decide to have lunch instead

Comment: re: validate: as this is regarding the city ticket, the right comparison is with an actual local transport ticket, which, in many cities, needs to be validated before the travel.

Comment: finally, re: city ticket: It's my understanding that you're expected to use it to go the the train station, it's not an unlimited day ticket, and so during a control, the ticket inspector will confirm that a/ you're going towards the train station, not away from it and b/ that the timing is more or less appropriate, although I'm less sure about that, because there's no reason why you couldn't go to the station early.

Comment: local transport tickets in Germany only need to be validated if they are undated. Eg. multi ride cards. But must people in Germany will ride on. a monthly pass, which does not require any action when entering a station.

Comment: If you're not staying in the city centre, please be careful about the exact validity area of your city ticket.

Comment: In Munich, the City Ticket is valid in zone M - https://www.mvv-muenchen.de/ticketshop-preise/tickets-tageskarten/city-ticket/index.html (try deepl.com for translation)

Comment: > You are expected to take the trains you selected during booking. < That is not a fully correct information. You must use the trains that have their numbers shown on the ticket proper (not the attached itinerary). If you have connections the number of which is not shown on the ticket you can use local trains other than those selected during booking, but limited by the validity of the ticket.

Answer (score 4):

> If yes then how will I validate my ticket as its for a different train

[DB](https://www.bahn.de/service/ueber-uns/inside-bahn/tipps-tricks/so-funktioniert-das-city-ticket) states :

> Das City-Ticket ist keine zusätzliche Fahrkarte: Wenn Sie eine Sparpreis- oder Flexpreis-Fahrkarte im Fernverkehr mit einer Reiseweite von über 100 Kilometern haben, dann ist das City-Ticket automatisch inklusive. Ihre Fernverkehrsfahrkarte hat dann den Zusatz „+City“ hinter der Bahnhofsbezeichnung, zum Beispiel „Köln +City“ oder „Berlin +City“. Da auf Ihrer Fahrkarte nur der Zielort „+City“ steht, können Sie in Städten mit mehreren DB-Bahnhöfen an jedem beliebigen Bahnhof im City-Ticket-Geltungsbereich ein- oder aussteigen.

*Google Translate:*

> The City-Ticket is not an additional ticket: If you have a saver fare
> or flex fare ticket for long-distance transport with a travel distance
> of more than 100 kilometers, then the City-Ticket is automatically
> included. Your long-distance ticket will then have the addition
> "+City" after the station designation, for example "Köln +City" or
> "Berlin +City". Since your ticket only says the destination "+City",
> you can get on or off at any station in the city ticket area in cities
> with several DB stations.
>
> If you have booked your ticket with "+City" on bahn.de or in DB
> Navigator , **you can simply show your online or mobile ticket on your
> smartphone for ticket inspection**. Of course, you can also print out
> your online ticket and present the printed PDF for verification.

Munich has no ticket barriers (like most (if not all) German cities), only validators for paper tickets, so you are free to enter with your valid DB ticket (but don't try to dodge the rules under any circumstances, it's a [criminal offense](https://www.dw.com/en/last-stop-jail-how-to-deal-with-fare-dodgers-in-germany/a-42407504) to fare dodge in German public transport)

[image]

---

> Its a "Sparpreis Europa" ticket, so its not flexible however my ticket says validity from Day1 - Day 2. Does it mean that if I miss my train then I catch another one with same ticket?

[DB](https://www.bahn.com/en/offers/saver-fare-europe/saver-fare-europe-austria) states :

> You may only travel on the long-distance trains (ICE, IC/EC) and on the days indicated on the ticket.
> When starting or completing your journey on **regional or local trains (RE, RB, IRE, S-Bahn)**, you are not restricted to specific trains or times. **Your journey must be completed by 10 am the following day.**

Comment: There is no need to validate. So the picture of the validator will only confuse the OP. Also it is not correct that the ticket can be used on any train...

Comment: @KristvanBesien "on regional or local trains (RE, RB, IRE, S-Bahn), you are not restricted to specific trains or times.", that's the part that can be used "on any train"